# Use Featured Image of Post as Header Image

Tags: post-thumbnails, theme-twenty-ten, headers

I have a blog on wordpress.com in which I make use of the Twenty Ten theme. For each Post I can set a Featured image.

On Wordpress.com that image is then displayed in the header above the menu.

I'd like to gain the same for a Wordpress.org setup. How can I do this?

Comment: isn't that already implemented in TwentyTen? I remember seeing the featured image in the header area..

Comment: I'm running a 3.0.5 site and it is not working that way. I think I need to debug further because I thought as well, that it should already work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely hakre but here is the code that shows the featured image for twenty-ten in header.php.The image sizing is defined in the functions.php file.

It also uses a function called http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header_image.

```
<?php
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() && current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
                    elseif ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Wyck, it's probably related that I downloaded too small images and expected to get them blown up: `$image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH`.

Comment: Yes it is [15 chars]